# No reference to parent scope when landed in error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an Angular directive that looks as follows

```
function parentFunction(parentService) {
    vm.childFunction = function() {
        parentService.funFunction()
          .then(function(response) { /* success */ }, 
                function(response) { /* failure */ });      
    };
}
```

I wanted to have access to parentService at

```
function(response) { /* failure */ }
```

But when I tried to access parentService at that point, it gives me the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: parentService is not defined
```

How do you use parentService in the `function(response) { /* failure */ }` section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`parentService`** should be passed as a parameter to your controller not your function

```
.controller('PhotoCtrl', ['parentService', function (parentService) {
      vm.childFunction = function() {
        parentService.funFunction()
          .then(function(response) { /* success */ }, 
                function(response) { /* failure */ });      
    };  
}])
```

Comment: Thanks Sajeetharan!